# Using an abstract class for generic tests

Tags: java, junit

Can I (and I guess more importantly, should I) wrap up generic junit tests in abstract classes?

For example, I have a set of classes under test that all use cacheing - obviously it would be good to have tests there to make sure I'm actually cacheing stuff correctly... the test code for this is nearly identical for each class, but with some minor details about the creation of the cached objects.

Is it OK to do something like this?

```
abstract class Foo {
    Baz baz;

    @Before
    abstract void setUp();

    @Test
    public void testMyBaz() {
        // ...
    }

}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    void setUp() {
        // set my baz
    }

    // other, more specific tests
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. I recommend you to try it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK to do that, but in the most cases, when you need that, you just need data factory, in JUnit it's done like that:

```
@RunWith(Parametrized.class)
public class SumTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 7}});
    }

    private int a, b, sum;
    public SumTest(int a, int b, int sum) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        Assert.assertEquals(a + b, sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah interesting - I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should do this. It allows you to reuse your abstract class, and customize your setup, while also running similar tests.

Answer (score 0):

In General, the unit tests needs to be more specific about what you are testing. Though there might be nothing wrong in your approach, you are fundamentally violating the principle of unit testing.

Try to test your caching logic independently and the feature using the caching logic independently. When testing for the features, ideally there is no need to retest the caching logic.